# Getting data from JSON Android

Tags: android, json, listview, parsing

I'm trying to retrieve the "Designacao" text to a listview, the problem is I have an array (paises) inside other array (no name BTW), how can I do it?

JSON:

```
[
 {
   paises: [
     {
       K_PAIS: "mz",
       K_CONTINENTE: 2,
       K_LINGUAGEM: "pt",
       Designacao: "Moçambique",
       URL_IMAGE_LARGE: "/Images/large-flags/mz-large.jpg",
       URL_IMAGE_SMALL: "/Images/flags/mz.png",
       Coord_LAT: -18.4335022,
       Coord_LONG: 30.9779447,
       Coord_Zoom: 6,
       Status: "OK"
     },
     {
       K_PAIS: "ma",
       K_CONTINENTE: 2,
       K_LINGUAGEM: "pt",
       Designacao: "Marrocos",
       URL_IMAGE_LARGE: "/Images/large-flags/ma-large.jpg",
       URL_IMAGE_SMALL: "/Images/flags/ma.png",
       Coord_LAT: 31.7252847,
       Coord_LONG: -11.5777195,
       Coord_Zoom: 6,
       Status: "OK"
    },
    {
       K_PAIS: "dz",
       K_CONTINENTE: 2,
       K_LINGUAGEM: "pt",
       Designacao: "Argélia",
       URL_IMAGE_LARGE: "/Images/large-flags/dz-large.jpg",
       URL_IMAGE_SMALL: "/Images/flags/dz.png",
       Coord_LAT: 27.7538925,
       Coord_LONG: -7.3521369,
       Coord_Zoom: 5,
       Status: "OK"
    }
    ],
    K_CONTINENTE: 2,
    K_LINGUAGEM: "pt",
    Designacao: "África",
    URL_IMAGE_LARGE: "/Images/large-flags/world-large.png",
    URL_IMAGE_SMALL: "/Images/flags/world.png",
    Coord_LAT: 3.6906886,
    Coord_LONG: 12.63657,
    Coord_Zoom: 3,
    Data_Criacao: "2017-03-01T00:00:00",
    Data_Alteracao: "2017-03-01T00:00:00",
    Status: "OK"
 },
 {
 paises: [
    {
       K_PAIS: "us",
       K_CONTINENTE: 3,
       K_LINGUAGEM: "pt",
       Designacao: "Estados Unidos da América",
       URL_IMAGE_LARGE: "/Images/large-flags/us-large.jpg",
       URL_IMAGE_SMALL: "/Images/flags/us.png",
       Coord_LAT: 37.09024,
       Coord_LONG: -95.712891,
       Coord_Zoom: 4,
       Status: "OK"
    },
    {
       K_PAIS: "mx",
       K_CONTINENTE: 3,
       K_LINGUAGEM: "pt",
       Designacao: "México",
       URL_IMAGE_LARGE: "/Images/large-flags/mx-large.jpg",
       URL_IMAGE_SMALL: "/Images/flags/mx.png",
       Coord_LAT: 23.3853163,
       Coord_LONG: -111.5655016,
       Coord_Zoom: 5,
       Status: "OK"
    }
    ],
       K_CONTINENTE: 3,
       K_LINGUAGEM: "pt",
       Designacao: "América do Norte",
       URL_IMAGE_LARGE: "/Images/large-flags/world-large.png",
       URL_IMAGE_SMALL: "/Images/flags/world.png",
       Coord_LAT: 54.5259614,
       Coord_LONG: -105.2551187,
       Coord_Zoom: 4,
       Data_Criacao: "2017-03-01T00:00:00",
       Data_Alteracao: "2017-03-01T00:00:00",
       Status: "OK"
    },
{},
{},
{},
{}
]
```

This is the important part of the java code on the mainactivity:

```
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    JSONArray paises = jsonObj.getJSONArray("paises");

                    //loop
                    for (int h = 0; h < paises.length(); h++) {
                        JSONObject c = paises.getJSONObject(h);

                        String K_PAIS = c.getString("K_PAIS");
                        String Designacao = c.getString("Designcao");

                        HashMap<String, String> pais = new HashMap<>();

                        pais.put("K_PAIS", K_PAIS);
                        pais.put("Designacao", Designacao);

                        listaPaises.add(pais);
                    }

                }
```

My code is largely based in: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Edited content:

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);
        Log.e(TAG, "Response from URL: " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {

                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);

                    JSONArray paises = jsonObject.optJSONArray("paises");

                    if (paises != null) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < paises.length(); j++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject1 = paises.getJSONObject(j);
                            System.out.println(jsonObject1.optString("Designacao"));
                            String K_PAIS = jsonObject1.getString("K_PAIS");
                            String Designacao = jsonObject1.getString("Designcao");

                            HashMap<String, String> pais = new HashMap<>();

                            pais.put("K_PAIS", K_PAIS);
                            pais.put("Designacao", Designacao);

                            listaPaises.add(pais);
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println(jsonObject.optString("Designacao"));
                }


            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json parsin error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errpr!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: that is not valid JSON, where are you getting it from?

Comment: Are you sure you pasted the JSON data correctly? I'm guessing you got it from a web service.

Comment: @lelloman Why? What's wrong with it?

Comment: you can try a json validator (just google "json validator"), but anyway in json the keys are string, it should be `"Designacao": "Moçambique"` not `Designacao: "Marrocos"`

Comment: @lelloman Well I used a validator and it says that the JSON code is OK, and you're right when you say designacao needs to be inside " ", I believe the problem is in the java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issues

1.) your response is a `JSONArray` not `JSONObject`

```
new JSONObject(jsonStr); // error
```

2.) Some of your `JSONObjects` are empty so you need to check if your `JSONObject`  contain any `paises` array.

3.) Nested arrays mean nested loops

```
        // JSONArray response
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonStr);

        // traverse your array objects          
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            // fetch object one by one using index i
            JSONObject jsonObject =array.getJSONObject(i);

            // optJSONArray will give you null if there is no paises jsonArray
            JSONArray paises =jsonObject.optJSONArray("paises");

            if (paises!=null) { // nullity check
                for (int j = 0; j < paises.length(); j++) { // nested loop for paises array
                    // fetch paises array objects
                    JSONObject jsonObject1 = paises.getJSONObject(j);
                    // ahh ! this is what you were looking for 
                    // optString give you "" empty string if there is no value
                    System.out.println(jsonObject1.optString("Designacao"));
                }
            }
            // fetch value which is outside paises array
            System.out.println(jsonObject.optString("Designacao"));
        }
```

Output :

```
MoÃ§ambique
Marrocos
ArgÃ©lia
Ã?frica
Estados Unidos da AmÃ©rica
MÃ©xico
AmÃ©rica do Norte
```

Note : avoid some weird `?` etc system font issue

Comment: But that is not android

Comment: so you want me to create a complete hashmap too ? or is there any other issue ?

Comment: The hashmap keep the same or no? I've updated the question with your changes included

Comment: you got a typo here ,it should be `jsonObject1.getString("Designacao");` not `Designcao`  , correct it and you are good to go